# openCV remap with BORDER_REFLECT not working

Tags: c++, opencv

I am calling the OpenCV `cv::remap` function, giving two maps, `map_x`and `map_y`for the x and y axes. These maps are set to -1 in the blank spaces( I am rotating images, there is some blank space that I want to fill with a mirror/reflection of the existing image).

I am calling the fuction like this

```
cv::remap(src_image, remaped_image, map_x, map_y, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_REFLECT);
```

but this results in an image with constant borders. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::remap` works with blink spaces in another way . If you set maps to `-1` for blank areas it extrapolates this points with extrapolated value of (-1, -1) source pixel. Thus, you got blank spaces filled with constant value. If you want fill this pixels with mirror value you need to provide appropriate coordinates to `cv::remap` even it will be out of border.

BTW, why you don't use `cv::warpAffine` + `cv::getRotationMatrix2D` for image rotation? Nice tutorial is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html). `cv::warpAffine` calls `cv::remap` internally with correct maps.

Comment: I oversimplified the problem. I don't have a matrix, I have my own projection functions, hence I have to create the maps myself. But what is the purpose of the BORDER_REFLECT argument anyway, if it won't do the borders for me?

Comment: If you want to use border support in `cv::remap` you need to provide coordinates of pixel for extrapolation. For example, if for destination pixel you need to get value of (-10, -5) source pixel (which is out of image), remap will extrapolate this value by specified border. You don't need to fill out of image pixels by (-1, -1), it makes wrong of `cv::remap`. @manatttta